# How to build old version of js v8?

Tags: linux, build, v8, archlinux

I'm building one old version of js v8 https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN, exactly for this purpose https://github.com/tunz/js-vuln-db/blob/master/v8/CVE-2017-5070.md. I try to checkout to an old branch about 17th May, 2017 of a branch commit(`git reset --hard a8424d592feff907c3f9a47310765c81321abe7b`), and use command `tools/dev/v8gen.py -b "V8 Linux64 - debug builder" -m client.v8 CVE-2017-5070 -vv` to build with it, but error occured:

```
################################################################################
/usr/bin/python -u tools/mb/mb.py gen -f infra/mb/mb_config.pyl -m client.v8 -b V8 Linux64 - debug builder out.gn/CVE-2017-5070

  Writing """\
  is_component_build = true
  is_debug = true
  target_cpu = "x64"
  use_goma = true
  v8_enable_backtrace = true
  v8_enable_slow_dchecks = true
  v8_has_valgrind = true
  v8_test_isolation_mode = "prepare"
  """ to /home/cui/github/v8/v8/out.gn/CVE-2017-5070/args.gn.

  /home/cui/github/v8/v8/buildtools/linux64/gn gen out.gn/CVE-2017-5070 --check
    -> returned 1
  ERROR at //gni/v8.gni:121:3: Dependency not allowed.
    executable(target_name) {
    ^------------------------
  The item //:mksnapshot
  can not depend on //build/config/sanitizers:deps
  because it is not in //build/config/sanitizers:deps's visibility list: [
    //build/config:exe_and_shlib_deps
  ]

  GN gen failed: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 304, in <module>
    sys.exit(gen.main())
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 298, in main
    return self._options.func()
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 166, in cmd_gen
    gn_outdir,
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 208, in _call_cmd
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-u', 'tools/mb/mb.py', 'gen', '-f', 'infra/mb/mb_config.pyl', '-m', 'client.v8', '-b', 'V8 Linux64 - debug builder', 'out.gn/CVE-2017-5070']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I don't know how to build old version of js v8, can you give me some advice?I really need to build this old version not the newest version

Answer (score -1):

Try running `gclient sync` after `git reset` (or `git checkout`, which would be the better alternative). Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too, but no use, the shell just blocking there.I try to find the reason about this,it's because the tool "gn" will do nothing, just blocking there.

Comment: `gclient sync` does not invoke `gn`, and is absolutely required before you can build. If you have a slow internet connection, it can take a while.

Comment: Yeah, I have executed command `gclient sync`,and gn will block at command `v8gen.py x64.release`.Then I trace this command, finally I found it will block at invoking gn.